# Google Captcha Static Resource to VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, managed-package, static-resources

I am using google Re captcha in my Visual force Page as below

The below one is working as expected.
**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Configure__c" extensions="GoogleCaptchaKey">
    <apex:slds />    
    <html>  
        <head> 
            <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.RecaptchaAPI}"/>
            <script   type="text/javascript">       
            
            grecaptcha.ready(function(){
                grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
                    'sitekey' :"{!googleCaptchaKey}",
                    'callback' : verifyCallback,
                }); 
            });
            //alert("{!googleCaptchaKey}");
            var verifyCallback = function(response) {
                console.log('inside verifyCallback');
                parent.postMessage("formvalidated", "{!$Site.BaseSecureUrl}");
            }; 
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="?" method="POST">
                <div id="html_element"></div>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
            </form>            
        </body>
    </html> 
</apex:page>
```

I am trying to using the captcha code in VF page instead of using static resource as below.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Configure__c" extensions="GoogleCaptchaKey">
    <apex:slds />    
    <html>  
        <head> 
            <!-- <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.RecaptchaAPI}"/> -->  
            <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Recaptcha_Library}"/>
            <script   type="text/javascript">       
            (function() {
                var w = window,
                    C = '___grecaptcha_cfg',
                    cfg = w[C] = w[C] || {},
                    N = 'grecaptcha';
                var gr = w[N] = w[N] || {};
                gr.ready = gr.ready || function(f) {
                    (cfg['fns'] = cfg['fns'] || []).push(f);
                };
                //w['__recaptcha_api'] = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/';
                (cfg['render'] = cfg['render'] || []).push('onload');
                w['__google_recaptcha_client'] = true;
                var d = document,
                    po = d.createElement('script');
                po.type = 'text/javascript';
                po.async = true;
                //po.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/_7Co1fh8iT2hcjvquYJ_3zSP/recaptcha__en.js';
                po.src = {!$Resource.Recaptcha_Library};
                po.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
                po.integrity = 'sha384-yF7E1ktGfbA26NWZZupkIgKSvH2WmFG90KyY3BzFp06blZkjALcng9gGnuW5hlae';
                var e = d.querySelector('script[nonce]'),
                    n = e && (e['nonce'] || e.getAttribute('nonce'));
                if (n) {
                    po.setAttribute('nonce', n);
                }
                var s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();
            grecaptcha.ready(function(){
                grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
                    'sitekey' :"{!googleCaptchaKey}",
                    'callback' : verifyCallback,
                }); 
            });
            //alert("{!googleCaptchaKey}");
            var verifyCallback = function(response) {
                console.log('inside verifyCallback');
                parent.postMessage("formvalidated", "{!$Site.BaseSecureUrl}");
            }; 
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="?" method="POST">
                <div id="html_element"></div>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
            </form>            
        </body>
    </html> 
</apex:page>
```

**Recaptcha_Library** Created new static resource which has the `https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/_7Co1fh8iT2hcjvquYJ_3zSP/recaptcha__en.js` code.

**Reason:** The above URL becomes invalid whenever the Google captcha is maintenance/released.

The above approach is not working, Can anyone help me what I am missing here

Thanks in advance.